# Bulk update column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where there is a column named "backfill_target" and its value is 1 but I need to change this to 20 for all 300 rows, how would I do this?

EDIT:

Here is a simplified version of my table

```
ID|name |backfill_target|first_record|second_record
0 | test| 1             |52          |54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to update every row.

```
UPDATE table SET backfill_target = 20
```

Answer (score 4):

try,

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET backfill_target = 20
WHERE backfill_target = 1
```

Comment: +1 as this is safer.. and shouldnt cause negative effects if you ran it again in the future..